# Regularities in a prime-exponent graph

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $\Omega(n)$ be the number of prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity,
i.e., if $n=p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$,
$\Omega(n) = e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_k$ ([OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega%28n%29,_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_%28with_multiplicity%29)).
For example, for $n=9000 = 2^3 3^2 5^3$, $\Omega(n)=8$.

The graph below plots, for each $n$, the point $(n,\Omega(n))$,
although on a log-scale; so I actually plot $q(n)= (\ln n,\Omega(n))$.
Those are the red dots. The blue segments of the graph connect $q(n)$ to all those
points below it on level $\Omega(n)-1$ that can reach $q(n)$
by multiplying by one prime. For example, $q(9000)$ would connect to $q(4500)$,
$q(3000)$, and $q(1800)$, multiplying by $2$, $3$, and $5$ respectively.
(The graph below only runs to $n=1024$.)

---

[image: PrimeExpoGraph]

---

In contrast to

> "[t]he chaotic course of $\Omega(n)$ through the natural numbers"
>   ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)),

this graph is considerably more regular than I anticipated.
Some aspects are easily explained. E.g., the parallel slanted lines
represent powers of primes, with the leftmost slanted line passing
through $q(2^m)$ up to $m=10$: $q(1024)= (6.93,10)$.

Could anyone explain the other regular qualitative features of
this graph—the stairstep right end, the density patterns visible,
the horizontal red-dot clustering, and any other discernible features?

Comment: +1, but if $p=p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$? You mean $n=p_1^{e_1}...$?

Comment: @draks...Thanks, *Yes*, I meant $n= \cdots$; corrected now.